# C# open browser with inserted words

Tags: c#, url, browser, textbox

I want to ask you guys if it is possible to do the following:
Type in textbox something like this "search pluto"
and then it must search for that last word.

This is how I did it but it doens't work because when I do that
my browser opens up twice.
One with "https://www.google.be/#q="
and the other tab that opens is the word that I wrote in
the textbox. Can somebody help me out of this please?

This is the code for this:

```
string url = "https://www.google.be/#

if (inputTBX.Text.Contains("search ") == true)
{
    inputTBX.Text.Replace("search ", "");
    string URL = url += inputTBX.Text;
    Process.Start(@"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe",
    URL);
    inputTBX.Clear();
}
```

Comment: Your question has less to do with anything that's tagged than what command line switches Chrome allows...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just as a test in a simple console app I tried the following and it worked launching my default browser

```
var t = "pluto";
Process.Start("http://google.com/search?q=" + t);
```

This also works

```
var t = "pluto";
Process.Start("https://www.google.be/search?q=" + t);
```

in your case you need to get your query string to be the following

> https://www.google.be/#q=pluto

your first problem is that you are trying to use the Replace method but you need to assign it into something here is a working solution of your code just tested notice the differences in what I have done

```
inputTBX.Test = "search pluto";
string url = "https://www.google.be/search?q=";

if (inputTBX.Contains("search "))
{
    inputTBX.Text = inputTBX.Replace("search ", "");
    string URL = url += inputTBX;
    Process.Start(URL); // this will launch your default web browser
    inputTBX.Clear();
}
```

since your query string has the word search in it.. you really don't need this line `if (inputTBX.Contains("search "))` but if you keep it it will work with if you pass `search planet pluto` for example in your textbox

Comment: Hey thx for awnsering but this is an error that I get:
http://i.imgur.com/MtLuu1f.png
cannot convert from 'string' to 'System.Windows.Forms.Control'

Comment: @ZionMees look at the update..`inputTBX.Text = inputTBX.Replace("search ", "");` needs to look at the `.Text` Property it was `inputTBX` was a typo.. this will now work the way the answer is please let me know if that fixes the issue

Comment: It works now but I've used a part of your code and a part of
the code down below.
Thanks for the help.

Comment: @ZionMees then you should mark it as the acceptable answer since it what I have shown you actually works

Answer (score 1):

This part

```
inputTBX.Text.Replace("search ", "");
```

Is seriously bad, because it will fail to do its job if you have input string like this

```
"search research on Beethoven's work"
```

If you want the key phrase to be "search ", you should do this instead

```
inputTBX.Text.Substring(("search ").Length); //this way it will skip the "search " phrase and use the rests of the phrase for searching
```

As for your process with the given URL, simply do

```
string url = "https://www.google.be/#q="; //notice the q= is missing in your code shown
Process.Start(url + inputTBX.Text.Substring(("search ").Length));
```

Comment: Thanks for anwsering  
I've tried this but I get an error:  
http://i.imgur.com/186eWyF.png  
What can I do about this ?

Comment: No, it shouldn't be like used like that. It is used to create string for input for the query, because the .Substring result is of string type. The if statement argument must remain boolean.

Comment: So you can still use yours for if condition: if (inputTBX.Text.Contains("search ") == true) but for the Replace, you should change it with mine (.Substring)

Comment: I am glad that you find it useful. Beware of using `Replace` whenever you do not really mean it (it will replace your entire string, while you only want to replace the early part!). You have another option `.Substring` to do so.